# Issue during the compilation of the apk

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard

When I try to deploy my android application in release mode an error occurs, specifically, if in the gradle i configure the params as follows:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    debuggable **true**
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    jniDebuggable false
    renderscriptDebuggable false
    renderscriptOptimLevel 3
    zipAlignEnabled true
}
```

The application is compiled and subsequent tests are successful, everything works correctly,if I modify the gradle so as to get the following

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    debuggable **false**
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    jniDebuggable false
    renderscriptDebuggable false
    renderscriptOptimLevel 3
    zipAlignEnabled true
}
```

The application does not work properly, specifically Internet connections (http / https calls fail).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you added proguard rules in the `proguard-rules.pro` files for all the libraries you are using?

Comment: be patient, could you be clearer / more precise?

Comment: any library  being used in your project have to keep some classes immuned from Proguard obfuscation. So, you have to add some rules in `proguard-rules.pro` to immune those classes from being obsfucated.

Comment: Yes i have added all rules